# AWSiOSSDKv2 is not available in Amazon link

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I just downloaded the amazon SDK form the link: http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/. But it does not contain the AWSiOSSDKv2.framework in it. When i used the version 2.0.15 and the above mentioned framework was present . But in the version 2.1.0 AWSiOSSDKv2 framework is not there.

Regards,
Chandrika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have split `AWSiOSSDKv2.framework` into the core and a framework per-service in version 2.1.0. See this blog [post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3OJX4PLAUJEH0/The-AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-iOS-2-1-0-Split-Frameworks) for more details.